# Is there a way to apply clip-path to a div without CSS?

Tags: svg, clip-path

I'm trying to clip a div with svg clip-path, because css rule `clip-path: url(#foo)` have poor support. So I thought may be i can attach svg clip-path to a div with html attribute `clip-path="#foo"`. Like in the example here - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking). But it doesn't work.

This is my svg element and div.

```
<svg class="svg-graphic">
      <defs>
       <clippath id="hexagonal-mask">
          <polygon points="130,0 0,160 0,485 270,645 560,485 560,160" />
       </clippath>
      </defs>

       <div class="element" clip-path="#hexagonal-mask">
         <div class="content">
           <h2>How it works</h2>
           <p>
             Download<span class="icon"></span>
           </p>
           <p>
             Watch video and Play games<span class="icon"></span>
           </p>
           <p>
             Choose your <span class="icon"></span>
           </p>
         </div>
       </div>
  </svg>
```

When i open an element inspector, i see that my div somehow appears outside of the svg element.
http://prntscr.com/ay7kxt
And clip-path doesn't apply.

Am i doing something wrong or is this aproach just doesnt work with divs, only with shapes like ,  ?

Comment: the div element has no clip-path attribute. In general only SVG maps attributes to styles, html does not.

Comment: What @RobertLongson said is true and I don't understand why you don't want to use CSS clip-path. But what he forgot to mention is that to include HTMLElements inside an `<svg>` one, you need to use a [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element, which does have a `clip-path` attribute. Note that `clip-path` should be referred with a `<funcIRI>` (`url(#idOfClipPath)`). https://jsfiddle.net/yefcL0gq/ Final note, I'm not sure `<foreignObject>` has better support than CSS `clip-path`

Comment: Also SVG is case sensitive so the element is called clipPath and not clippath

Comment: @Kaiido dont want to use css rule clip-path, because it doesnt work correctly in Mozilla and IE / Edge

Comment: I think that CSS clip-path referring to an svg clipPath is supported in FF for a while, whereas foreignObject is only supported in latest IE versions.

Comment: FF doesnt recognise `clip-path: url(#foo)`. On Can-I-Use stated that it is support only `clip-path: url()` syntax, whatever this means. Also, my IE11 desplay clip with foreignObject strange. It hide the whole div, not only the part, that is described in `<polygon>`

Comment: Actually FF has one of the best support of funcIRI in external files. Chrome is broken there. If your CSS is external it should be clip-path:url(yourFile.html#yourClipPathElem). And about Ie11 it sounds more like it doesn't support foreignObject :-)